# Unable to update "Secure Boot dbx" : no volumes of type ... (It's a different problem here)

Tags: grub2, uefi, disk, secure-boot, fwupd

I've got a secure boot dbx update (78->217) waiting in my Ubuntu Software app. When I try to install it, I get this error message :
" Blocked executable in the ESP, ensure that grub and shim are up to date: no volumes of type c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b "

I've searched a lot of forums for an answer, but I kept finding the solution where an old shim file needs to be deleted in the EFI directory. But in each of those cases, the error message was showing the name of the file that caused the update to be interrupted. In my case it seems to be something missing. image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4y4M.png)
Previously when I did updates through command line, I kept getting a message saying that there is no public key for signing a VirtualBox package.

Since today (maybe I did something wrong ?), when I do apt-get upgrade, it says (I partially translated from french) :

```
setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.173.2~20.04.1+2.04-1ubuntu47.4) ...
mount: /var/lib/grub/esp: the special device /dev/disk/by-id/ata-TOSHIBA_MQ01ACF050_85L8CJQDT-part1 does not exist.
```

and
`dpkg:` [blabla...] `subprocess returned error code 32`  image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMy7R.png)

When running `ls /dev/disk/by-id/` I see that the mentioned device doesn't exist, and I've got some ata-Micron...  instead. image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbsJr.png)

Last year I changed from a HDD from the brand TOSHIBA to a SSD from the brand Micron. Could it be that this is causing trouble in updating and configuring grub ?

By the way, I've not had trouble updating software that is running on the OS, which is still Ubuntu 20.04

Attached are images of what I'm talking about.
[image: The Error message I get in the Ubuntu software app]
[image: The error message when trying an upgrade in the command line]
[image: List of the content of the disk directory : there is no TOSHIBA but Micron]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438076/what-do-i-need-to-update-secure-boot-for/1447133#1447133

Comment: It's not exactly the same in my case, as the error message doesn't tell me which file exactly is causing trouble, and I found I problem when trying to update grub.