# "Import OS Updates" notification won't go away at log in

Tags: updates, notification, 23.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10 and, after a firmware update, I keep having an "Important OS Updates..." notification showing at every log in. I keep dismissing it, but it still shows up every time I log in.

I tried disabling notifications entirely in the settings for several applications (Ubuntu Software, Snap Store, Portal, Snapd User Session Agent, Evolution alarm) without success. I also read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469200/how-can-i-dismiss-software-updates-installed-notification) that I could remove the file `/var/lib/PackageKit/offline-update-completed`, but there is no such file. With `locate`, I also tried to find any other file with `completed` in its name, but found nothing relevant.

It's not a big deal, but it's getting really annoying.

Any idea?

Comment: Just to be clear, the text of the notification is: "An important OS update has been installed" - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's the otherwise very common notification that normally goes away once dismissed.

Comment: Had issues with repeated `UEFI dbx` update notifications. Fixed using `fwupdmgr clear-results` -- see https://askubuntu.com/a/1498444.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick:

```bash
$ killall snap-store
$ sudo snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10
```

Comment: Thanks for posting it! I had the same issue, and it worked for me too.

Comment: This worked for me too.